# Can you solve​ two equations simultaneously

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Solve for $x$ and $y$ if $4xy=-15$ and $4x^3+4y^3=49$

Comment: $x=\frac{5}{2}, y = -\frac{3}{2}$ is the only real solution (with permutations).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Cubing the first equation, you deduce the system:
$$ x^3y^3=-\frac{3375}{64},\qquad x^3+y^3=\frac{49}4$$
This is the classical problem of finding two numbers, given their sum and their product. It is well known from the theory of quadratic equations, that $x^3$ and $y^3$ are the roots of the equation:
$$t^2-\frac{49}4 t-\frac{3375}{64}=0\iff 64t^2-49\cdot 16\, t-3375 =0 \iff (8t)^2-98(8t)-3375=0.$$
There remains to solve for $8t$, then deduce $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 3):

Substituting $y=-\frac{15}{4x}$ from the first equation in the second  we find:
$$
64x^6-784x^3-3375=0
$$

that, for $t=x^3$ becomes a second degree equation with solutions:

$$
t_1= -\frac{27}{8} \qquad t_2= \frac{125}{8}
$$
From wich you can find the real and complex solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Say $a= 2x$ and $b= 2y$. Then $b= -15/a$ and $a^3+b^3= 98$ so we have to solve $$a^3-{15^3\over a^3} = 98$$

This is quadratic equation in $t=a^3$: $$t^2-98t-15^3=0$$

Since $D= 98^2+4\cdot 15^3 = 152$ so $$t_{1,2} = {98\pm 152\over 2}$$

So ($a_1 = 5$ and $ b_1= -3$) and ($a_2 = -3$ and $ b_2= 5$) ... as Ahmad already mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

WOLOG, assume $x \ge y$. Let $u = x+y$, we have

$$49 = 4(x^3+y^3) = 4(u^3 - 3xy u) = 4u^3 - 3(4xy)u = 4u^3 + 45u$$
This leads to
$$0 = 4(u^3-1) + 45(u-1) = (u-1)(4(u^2 + u + 1) + 45 ) = (u-1)(4u^2 + 4u + 49)$$
Notice $4u^2 + 4u + 49 = (2u+1)^2 + 48 \ne 0$, this means $x + y = u = 1$.

Together with $x - y = \sqrt{(x+y)^2 - 4xy} = \sqrt{1 + 15} = 4$, we find
$$(x,y) = \left(\frac{5}{2}, -\frac{3}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Like @john, substitute the double of the unkowns, for convenience:

$$uv=-15,u^3+v^3=2\cdot49.$$

Then multiplying the second equation by $u^3$ and rearranging,

$$u^6-2\cdot49\,u^3-15^3=0.$$

This is a quadratic equation in $u^3$, with solutions

$$u^3=-27,125$$ then

$$x=-\frac32,y=\frac52$$ or conversely.